# Write java program as a String using Python

Tags: java, python, json

I am trying to write a script that will generate a java file that will be used in Android Studio. the reason I am doing that is because I will be generating different JSON files with different information and I want to generate the appropriate java files using these JSON files if that make sense. Currently, I am testing the whole process of writing a simple java program in a file in the following python script:

```
dataClass = "public class data {"
mainMethodHeader = "public static void main(String args[]) {"
sys = "System.out.println(\"Hello World!\");"
closingbracket = "}"
wholeProgram = dataClass + mainMethodHeader + sys + closingbracket + closingbracket
json.dump(wholeProgram, open('data.java', 'w+'))
```

The problem is I cannot compile the data.java since it is string:

[image]

Any idea how I can force non-string output in the file so it can be compiled by the java compier?

Comment: Why are you using JSON at all when you're just concatenating strings? Just `open('data.java', 'w+').write(wholeProgram)` would do what you want..

Comment: A Java source file is *not* a JSON string.

Comment: I was using the JSON library before that. And yes, you are right that java program is not a string, I just did not realize that :) Thank you for your sugestions! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`json.dump` will result in a JSON representation of your string. (E.g. `foo` becomes `"foo"`.)

You should just write the content of the string directly into the file:

```
with open('data.java', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(wholeProgram)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! :)